# Planing route with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript, nativescript-vue, google-directions-api

I need to show on Android in my app google maps and also should be a possibility planing route between two points and need the possibility to set way to travel (walking, driving).

Which package should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The package would be `[nativescript-google-maps-sdk][1]`, but the docs referenced above would be very pertinent if you REALLY want to display the route within your own app.  Alternatively, you could compose and open a url that would open the default maps app with the route / directions and have all the expected function there.  To do this you'd use the [nativescript-geolocation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation) plugin to get the current location, and the utils.openUrl method to open the composed URL.  You'll also need to use `https://github.com/nathanaela/nativescript-permissions` to handle requesting permission.  The resulting code can look something like:

```
  url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=" + loc.latitude + "," + loc.longitude + "&destination=" + addr.replace(/ /g, "+") + "";
  utils.openUrl(url);
```

Comment: this variant is not very good

Answer (score -1):

Use this API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview it will help in getting directions and route.

Comment: I need package, plugin for native script vue, and not docs...